# modify an Ajax file upload plugin

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to modify this jQuery plugin: http://tutorialzine.com/2013/05/mini-ajax-file-upload-form/
what I'm trying to do is: when the image is done uploading, instead of the progress bar I want to display the image.

In script.js there is this function:

```
progress: function(e, data){

    // Calculate the completion percentage of the upload
    var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);

    // Update the hidden input field and trigger a change
    // so that the jQuery knob plugin knows to update the dial
    data.context.find('input').val(progress).change();

    if(progress == 100){
        data.context.removeClass('working');
    }
}
```

so instead of the progress bar I'm able to display some text:

```
    if(progress == 100){
        data.context.removeClass('working');
     $('.test').html('test');
    }
```

but what I need is to put an url, so I want to add a parameter to the progress function, but I searched everywhere and I don't see where the progress function is called.
Does anybody can help me please?

Comment: If you're looking for the SRC of the file, it's going to be in the `e` param of the function. I don't know exactly what, just `console.log(e)`, then step through it until you find the SRC of the uploaded image.